# Which sub-type should I choose for a Standard Visitor visa and when will it expire?

Tags: paperwork, chinese-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

In February, I am about to give a lecture in UK. Right after that lecture, I will leave UK. Six months later, I will attend my friend's wedding in London in July. I was suggested to apply to the standard visitor visa. I have the following three questions. Thanks in advance.

1. In the Visa4UK application system, I cannot find the so called "standard visitor visa". After selecting "visit", I still need to select among different types. The first question is that shall I choose "Tourism" or "Business", or it does not matter.
   [image]
2. Suppose I choose "Business". The second question is that shall I choose "6 months" or "Long term"? I will have two visits in the predicted future. Each visit will not exceed one week. I asked because I am not sure when will the VISA expire, and whether or not the VISA allows for multiple entries.
   [image]
3. The last question is that shall I provide details for both visits or simply the first one.

Comment: What is your nationality/citizenship?
Do you have any existing record of travel to the UK? Is the lecture paid?

Comment: @CMaster My nationality is CHINA. All expense of the lecture is paid by the host. However, I will not earn any money by giving the lecture.

Answer (score 5):

Nice observation!  This is a 'known problem' within UKVI that the online form did not sync up after the rule change last April.

Regardless of what you enter, your application will be considered against [Appendix V of the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) and if you are successful, you will receive a 'standard visitor visa' (or to be exact, 'entry clearance').

Based upon what you wrote, you can fill out the form like this...

[image]

or like this...

[image]

Both options amount to the same thing.  You can select the one that states your case best if you want.

**The second question is that shall I choose "6 months" or "Long term"?**

They will issue you a 6 month visa regardless of what you choose.  Qualifying for a long-term visa is a difficult ordeal requiring a lengthy history of travel to the UK and an on-going premise.  Two visits does not qualify as a premise.  Note: they will keep the difference in fees.

**The last question is that shall I provide details for both visits or simply the first one.**

Provide all the details. For a start date, select the date for which both events are in the same 6 month period and explain both events.  If both of your planned events are not in the same 6 month window, you will have to make two applications.  They will not, for example, issue a 7 month or 8 month visa.

---

Note: UKVI may fix this problem on their site next May. Or they may not.

Comment: e.g. 2 Feb to 1 Aug should cover both events.